# Excel Custom Data Validation for numbers with max 2 decimals

Tags: excel, vba

Need a custom data validation to be sure user do not enter numbers with more than 2 decimals.

What mut be accepted:

- 1
- 1,2
- 1,23

What mut be rejected:

- hello
- 1,234

Where comma `,` is the decimal separator.

Thanks

Comment: Surely someone with your rep and badges would know this is not how SO works.

Comment: That's not as easy as it seems... Others suggestions did not work well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting `Custom` data validation and the following formula:

```
=ROUND(A1,2)=A1
```

where A1 is address of validated cell. Replace comma with semicolon if it's your formula separator.